# Use non-Laravel package in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use this package within my Laravel project:

https://github.com/bkuhl/simple-ups

I am however struggling to use it within my controller as it has an hyphen within its path.

I have tried doing:

```
use Bkuhl\simple-ups\src\SimpleUPS\UPS.php
```

but it does not seem work. Does anyone have a guide as to how I can use it within my controller?

Comment: If the package is installed via composer, try doing `use SimpleUPS\UPS;`

Comment: Where and how are you installing the `package`?

Comment: 1st install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) in your system, then follow the instruction in [README.md](https://github.com/bkuhl/simple-ups) installation by composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use SimpleUPS\UPS;`
You can view the namespace of the class here
https://github.com/bkuhl/simple-ups/blob/master/src/SimpleUPS/UPS.php